# What search engine software does Area 51 use?

Tags: discussion, search, area-51, technology

I was on the Area 51 Stack Exchange site and used the search bar. I was confused as to why it was working so quickly and that's when I realized it was using JavaScript.

Eventually I found that you can search using the URL since it was using post originally
https://area51.stackexchange.com/search/results?q=apple

I know there's only about 110 records, but is this search page still using [Elasticsearch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elasticsearch) or some other search engine like regular [Lucene](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucene), etc.?

Comment: See [Which tools and technologies are used to build the Stack Exchange Network?](/q/10369/289905).

Comment: Re *"...using post"*: Do you mean *"...using [POST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_%28HTTP%29)"*? The URL results in using [GET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods). Do you mean you derived the URL from spying on a POST request?

Comment: Yes, I read the payload post data and made it GET instead.